# Jenkins: not make Parent build fail is child fails, but throw a WARNING?

Tags: jenkins, build

I have a Jenkins Job which I have configured to use the *Trigger/call builds on other projects* plugin. My parent job *P* triggers a child job *C*. *P* also invokes a lot more of other jobs, but specially for *C*, I need to do this: if *C* fails, *P* needs to continue running to its end, but the final result of the build can't be 100% a success. Is there a way to throw like a WARNING message or mark the build as Unstable?

I know I might be using the proper job for this, sorry in advance.

Comment: Are these freestyle jobs or pipeline? Please paste a screenshot of the section where you are calling `job C`

Comment: It is free style. Here is https://ibb.co/9H8R58N

Comment: You are trying to achieve an `if-else` condition which does not exist in `Freestyle` jobs it cannot offer the flexibility you require. You can convert `Job P` into a `Pipeline` job and with a little groovy scripting, easily achieve what you are asking for including marking the build as `unstable`. Ref: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019828412-Pipeline-How-to-write-a-declarative-pipeline-to-invoke-another-job